# Getting the index of a slice

Tags: regex, scala

I want to do some processing on a string in Scala. The first stage of that is finding the index of articles such as: `"A "`, `" A "`, `"a "`, `" a "`. I am trying to do that like this:

```
"A house is in front of us".indexOfSlice("\\s+[Aa] ")
```

I think this should return `0`, as the substring is first matched in the first position of the string.

However, this returns `-1`.

Why does it return `-1`? Is the regex I am using incorrect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other answers as I type this are just missing the point. Your problem is that `indexOfSlice` doesn't take a regexp, but a sub-sequence to seach for in the sequence. So fixing the regexp won't help at all.

Try this:

```
val pattern = "\\b[Aa]\\b".r.unanchored
for (mo <- pattern.findAllMatchIn("A house is in front of us, a house is in front of us all")) {
    println("pattern starts at " + mo.start)
}
//> pattern starts at 0
//| pattern starts at 27
```

(with fixed regex, too)

Edit: counter-example for the popular but wrong suggestion of `"\\s*[Aa] "`

```
val pattern2 = "\\s*[Aa] ".r.unanchored 
for (mo <- pattern2.findAllMatchIn("The agenda is hidden")) {
  println("pattern starts at " + mo.start)
}
//> pattern starts at 9
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a mistake in your regex. your regex is searching for

1. at least once space (\s+)
2. a letter (either A or a)

but string you are matching doesn't contain space in beginning. that's why It's not returning you index 0 but -1.

you could write your regex as `"^\\s*[Aa] "`

Here is example:

```
val text = "A house is in front of us";

val matcher = Pattern.compile("^\\s*[Aa] ").matcher(text)
var idx  = 0;

if(matcher.find()){
  idx = matcher.start()
}
println(idx)
```

it should return **0** as expected.

Comment: This  misses the point that indexOfSlice doesn't take a regexp, and also matches Aa  at the end of words (e.g. "agenda") (because \\s* matches the empty string)

Comment: Please see test case. This solution answers what OP is asking. not any arbitrary situation. He is specifically asking for what's wrong with his version of regex.

Comment: "The first stage of that is finding the index of articles such as: "A ", " A ", "a ", " a "".  Yours does not do that. It finds "A" or "a" followed by a space (in fact, the "\\s*" is not needed - your solution would match the same things without it. And, finally, you didn't even test it.  `"A house is in front of us".indexOfSlice("\\s*[Aa] ")` returns -1 (because, again, indexOfSlice _does not take a regex_)

Comment: Please accept m apology for disagreeing. Can you just test above regex. \s* means match if there are spaces or even not. So it doesn't matter if there is space or spaces or even no space at all

Comment: Exactly! So you would match this string "The agenda is hidden", because there's an "a" followed by " ". And run your own test case - it returns -1!

Comment: See my edit to my answer to demonstrate your regex produces false hits.

Comment: but you are using findAllMatchIn which is greedy. that's why it's matching at end of string. try `"^\\s*[Aa]"`

Comment: for sake of argument, my regex works perfectly. please see my updated example

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104757/discussion-between-saleem-and-the-archetypal-paul).

Comment: Greedy is what is needed, and no, your regex doesn't work. It matches the article only if it is at the beginning of the string. So yes, it matches the one test case that the OP gives, but the question is clear to me - the requirement is to find the article anywhere in the string.  I give up arguing the point, you're still wrong and hopefully the OP will be along to clarify soon.